# Numpy Arrays Correlation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, correlation

I have two variables as numpy arrays and I want to calculate Pearson's correlation between then. In my case the correlation is over the time, where each array is a time step.

For example:

Pearson's correlation between x[0, 0, 0] and y[0, 0, 0], x[1, 0, 0] and y[1, 0, 0]...

For each element.

In the end I will have an array with correlation result.

My arrays:

```
>>> print x
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]
  [ 6  7]]

 [[ 8  9]
  [10 11]
  [12 13]
  [14 15]]

 [[16 17]
  [18 19]
  [20 21]
  [22 23]]]

>>> print y
[[[10  11]
  [12  13]
  [14  15]
  [16  17]]

 [[18 19]
  [20 21]
  [22 23]
  [24 25]]

 [[26 27]
  [28 29]
  [30 31]
  [32 33]]]
```

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html

Comment: I try this, but it's for one dimension array.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you want with copyable code showing what you've tried?

Comment: It's hard, for me at least, to tell exactly what result you are after. Try and write a short example where you compute the result you want the "ugly way", e.g. by looping manually and calling the scipy function each time. [Make it copyable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the previous comment says, which means add the import statements, hardcode some data or generating it randomly with one of the `np.random` routines, etc. This is the best way to get a great answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Mr E, if I was not clear

My arrays dimensions is:

```
print (x.shape)
x = (20, 21, 22)

print (y.shape)
y = (20, 21, 22)
```

So, I resolved my problem writing the code below.

If somebody has a better idea let me know!

```
import numpy as np

def corr_pearson(x, y):

    """
    Compute Pearson correlation.
    """

    x_mean = np.mean(x, axis=0)
    x_stddev = np.std(x, axis=0)

    y_mean = np.mean(y, axis=0)
    y_stddev = np.std(y, axis=0)

    x1 = (x - x_mean)/x_stddev
    y1 = (y - y_mean)/y_stddev

    x1y1mult = x1 * y1

    x1y1sum = np.sum(x1y1mult, axis=0)

    corr = x1y1sum/20.

    return corr
```